# How to explicitly specify the correct DTEXEC file when executing a SSIS package

Tags: ssis, dtexec

I have an SSIS package created in visual studio 2010. I want to deploy the package to the file system(not into SQL Server) on the destination server. However, i have just been informed that the target server only has SQL Server 2005 installed.

The package will be installed using SSIS package installation utility and i am afraid the DTEXEC version of SSIS 2005 which is on the server might not successfully execute my package.

So is there away i can copy a newer DTEXEC file from my machine and have it included in the package folder such that i can explicitly call it when executing the package on the target server?

Does any one know of some sort of a script or some way that i can use to run a SSIS package developed in VS 2010 on a server that has the DTEXEC utility of SSIS 2005?

NOTE that this package doesn't have to be deployed in SQL Server, just in the file system.

Answer (score 1):

I would upgrade the server (at a minimum, the SSIS Instance) to SQL Server 2012 or higher.